# magento -search not working properly

Tags: magento

hai

I have a  magento web site. In this the search function compare with product name, description, sku and part number. I want to modify this. ie having to compare only with the product name, short description and Sku, How is it possible.Is there is any settings in admin side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the product attributes.

For each attribute you can decide if this attribute should be considered in the quick and/or advanced search.

Don't forget to update your indices!

Comment: I think the related products which have the search keyword displays, how i will remove this